# JQuery select2 e.val undefined on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

My `select2` on `change` event does not fire `e.val`.

code:

```
$(".clienteselect").select2({
        width: "200",
        placeholder: "<?php echo $dicescolhecli; ?>",
})
.on("change",function(e){
    console.log(e.val) ;
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="clienteselect">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1"> Manuel Silva </option>
    <option value="2"> Luis Antonio </option>
    <option value="3"> Jose Rodrigues </option> 
</select>
```

`e.val` always returns `undefined`. Did I miss something?

Comment: `e` is a reference to the change event, which has no `val()` method; instead use `e.target.value`, `this.value`, `$(this).Val()`.

Comment: I Will try It tomorrow then

Comment: Note: my previous comment suffered from autocorrect; the last piece of code should have been: `$(this).val()` with a lowercase `v` character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e is a reference to the `change` event you subscribed to, you can use the target (html element) to get your select2 component and find the value :

```
$(".clienteselect").select2({
  width: "200",
  placeholder: "Select",
}).on("change",function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).select2("val"));
});
```

hope this helps.